# IsInDesignModeStatic always returns false in Visual Studio 2012 WPF Projects

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, mahapps.metro

I have several projects designed around MVVMLite and MahApps.Metro libraries however I've never been able to get

ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic

to return true when executing from Visual Studio 2012. I'm calling it in the same way as the MVVMLite tutorials and examples i.e. in the ViewModelLocator constructor.

I normally work around this by avoiding putting context sensitive code in my constructors but it would really help to get some design time data sometimes. I can't find anyone else with the same problem!

Any ideas?

Cheers

Dave

Comment: `to return true when executing from Visual Studio 2012`. Not sure if I follow you right but `IsInDesignModeStatic` returns true when the code is run via the VS / Blend **Designer**. not the project itself getting built and executed by Visual Studio.

Comment: To check it's actually working, you can always activate the design mode in say blend, when you have that instance of expression blend attached as a process from visual studio. MVVM Light's Author shows it in his intro video. [Understanding the MVVM Pattern - MIX10 session](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/kreekman/techdays-2010-understanding-the-model-view-viewmodel-pattern) Go to **21:00** minutes into the video and watch the session for about 5 minutes and you'll see the process of attaching blend to VS and checking the DesignMode value and executing design-mode code.

Comment: Hey Viv, I've just had a light on moment! I was thinking all the wrong way about it! So it's only to allow test data when the classes are being executed from within the designer pages. That really makes sense now. Thanks for clearing it up for me :-)